# Problem with get_abosulute_url when using @models.permalink decorator in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-urls, permalinks

Having some trouble using the permalink decorator when defining get_absolute_url for one of my models that i just cant seem to figure out!

Im calling object.get_absolute_url() but it doesn't seem to return anything whilst using the permalink decorator.

## model.py

```
@models.permalink
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return ('view_gig', (), {
        'id': self.id,
        'token': self.token})
```

## urls.py

```
(r'^gigs/(?P<id>[\d+])/(?P<token>[\w+])(/?)', view_gig),
```

## template

```
<a href="{{ gig.get_absolute_url }}">View More Info</a>
```

stragely if i remove

```
@models.permalink
```

from the get_absolute_url() definition its returns

```
('view_gig', (), {'id': self.id, 'token': self.token})
```

in the url in the template.

this is driving me insane thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use:

```
(r'^gigs/(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<token>[\w-]+)(/?)', view_gig),
```

Comment: :( this hasnt solved it either, in shell if i loop over all the gigs then call get_absolute_url() on the object i get a NoReverseMatch exception error

Im guessing its defo something to do with it not matching the regex!! Thanks for the answer, any other ideas??

Comment: I think some extra context is needed around the possible values of the 'token' field in order to get you an exact answer.

Comment: hey i changed things about abit and got it working think the main problem was some errors in the regex
(r'^gigs/(?P<id>[\d+])/(?P<token>[\w+])(/?)', view_gig),
(/?) i changed this to /? and re worked the url conf a little to look like this
url(r'^gigs/(?P<id>\d+)/([\w-]+)/?', 'gigs.views.view_gig', name="view-gig") im now defining get_absolute_url as 

 @models.permalink
 def get_absolute_url(self):
   return ('view-gig', [str(self.id), self.token]

Decided i didnt actually need to pass token to the view function thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1):

What if you try `(r'^gigs/(?P<id>[\d+])/(?P<token>[\w+])', view_gig),` ?

Comment: this wouldnt work as token is a slug so the regex needs to match the hyphons in the regex ie ([\w-]+)

i have solved this now the url conf looks like so:

url(r'^gigs/(?P<id>\d+)/([\w-]+)/?', 'gigs.views.view_gig', name="view-gig")


thanks for you answer